# Logging in to facebook from an Android app redirects to browser

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

We are using Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android. From our App we allow users to request for login to facebook to get the access token. It used to work quite well. 
Today (10 may 2013), when we want to login, the webview loaded by facebook is redirecting to the browser on the phone. This we are seeing only from morning. Yesterday the same code was working fine. 
 Even the sample app Scrumptious is having the same behavior.
Is anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: Do you have Facebook App installed on your phone?

Comment: yes, our app is installed on phones. However, no native facebook app is installed on that phone. BTW, we are not using SSO.

Comment: so its because of that

Comment: is it because native facebook app is not installed on the phone? our app was working fine yesterday. Is that a requirement from today?

Comment: No dude, its my observation, whenever you try to login from fb on phone that dont have native fb app installed, it redirects you to browser

Comment: This should not be the case. The webview should not redirect to the browser. What type of phone are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you dont have native facebook android app installed.

If native fb android app is installed, it will not redirect you to browser, only pop up will come with request for permission.

Comment: yes, I tried your suggestion. it works the way you mentioned. Thanks for your help. Marking it as answer.

Comment: My original question remains, though. is Facebook native app installation a pre-requisite. what changed from yesterday?

Comment: No native fb app installation is not pre-requisite.
It just changes the way app(our apps) logs in.

Comment: If native FB is not installed, the login webview is redirecting to browser. My app is not getting called back at all. So, if native app is not installed, I am hosed :-(

Comment: Then there is something wrong in your code.Whether the native app is installed or not, your app always gets a callback.
Are you overriding `onActivityResult()` properly?

Refer this link - https://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5556996 
It is just a sample for sharing status on fb.I will add for fb login tomorrow.Note that above link is just a skeleton.

Comment: I have added skeleton code on github forFbLogin, you can refer it here-> https://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5560725

You can also consider FbLoginButton -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton

Comment: @user2371423 You might want try changing the oauth url in your webview to this one: 

`protected static String OAUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";`

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing the oauth url in your webview to this one:

```
protected static String OAUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"
```